# OPenCV boosting differences

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I am working with OpenCV for a project used for recognition and I had a general question regarding the API and it's terms. I've looked online and couldn't find anything specific to this but I was wondering what the differences were regarding the Discrete Adaboost, Real AdaBoost, LogitBoost, and Gentle AdaBoost. If anyone could direct me to a pros v cons or a general description about these so that I may research which would be useful.

**Update**
I have added a link to a powerpoint file that goes over the different variations of the Boosting techniques. Hope this hopes someone else out there.
[Adaboost powerpoint](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~dhoiem/presentations/Adaboost_Tutorial.ppt)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a simple "always use technique X" otherwise there wouldn't be a need for all the others . You really have to understand the details and experiment.

see [The opencv discussion](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/boosting.html) and [A list of papers and technical summaries](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~schapire/boost.html)

Comment: I understand that and I know that I will have to look into them. I just wanted some links to describe the benefits of each one so that I can find out which would be the best to use.

Comment: Haven't really found a simple/beginner intro. You might have to hit the papers in the second link. If you do find a good tutorial please post the link here !